# if 文 簡単なデータ処理

Tags: python

初心者なので言葉足らずかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします．

csvファイル（ファイル名"data-path"）で1列目に1行目から順に以下の様に書かれています．
1行目から見ていき最初に1.0以上の数値（この場合1.5）を見つけ出しそれまでのデータ（1－4行目）を削除しそれをcsvで保存するプログラムを書こうとしていましたがうまくいかないので質問させていただきました．一応私はif文を用いて書こうと思っていました．

**CSVファイルの例:**

```
0.1
0.3
0.2
0.9
1.5
0.8
1.1
以下略
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data_path_A = '201016tamesi.csv'

#データの読み込み
data_all_A = pd.read_csv(data_path_A)
data_all_A = np.array(data_all_A)

for i in range(90000):
    if data_all_A[i] > 0.1: #参照値が0.03
         data_all_A=np.delete(data_all_A,i,0)
    else:
        break
        
print(data_all_A)
```

Answer (score 2):

`dropwhile()` を使うのが一番楽かと思います。

```
from itertools import dropwhile

data = (0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 0.8, 1.1)

for x in (dropwhile(lambda y: y < 1.0, data)):
    print(x)

1.5
0.8
1.1
```

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile

補足(編集)
ループで参照する配列のデータを削除すると要素のインデックスがずれるので基本やってはいけません(コスト的にもおすすめしません)。新たに配列を作るやり方にすべきです。

Comment: お二方ともありがとうございます．試してみたところできました！
このようなデータ列が3列あっても列ごとに処理する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) を利用して、`1.0` 以上の最初の行を決定します。

```py
import pandas as pd

data_path_A = '201016tamesi.csv'

data_all_A = pd.read_csv(data_path_A, header=None)
data_all_A = (
  data_all_A.loc[data_all_A[0].ge(1.0).idxmax():]
  .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(data_all_A)

=>
     0
0  1.5
1  0.8
2  1.1
```