# 2列ではスムーズにいっていたが17列にしたとたん実行完了しなくなった

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

[以前回答していただいた手法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71712/csv%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E5%88%97%E3%81%94%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)を参考にcsvに保存された17列のデータを各列において1行目に2以上の数値からスタートするプログラミングを書きましたが実行にものすごく時間がかかり1日たっても終わる気配がありません．どこが間違っていますか．

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import dropwhile
%matplotlib inline

data = '1214.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data)
data = np.array(data)

from itertools import dropwhile, zip_longest

d0 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,0])] 
d1 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,1])]
d2 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,2])] 
d3 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,3])]
d4 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,4])] 
d5 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,5])]
d6 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,6])] 
d7 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,7])]
d8 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,8])] 
d9 = [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,9])]
d10= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,10])] 
d11= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,11])]
d12= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,12])] 
d13= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,13])]
d14= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,14])] 
d15= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,15])]
NewData = np.array([d0, d1,d2, d3,d4, d5,d6, d7,d8, d9,d10, d11,d12, d13,d14, d15]） 
print(NewData)
np.savetxt('1214-945.csv', NewData, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: その CSV ファイルは何行あるのでしょう？ ところで、`dropwhile` はイテレータなので、`list(dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,0]))` としても同じ結果になります。

Answer (score 0):

列のインデックスが`0`～`15`までと、16列分指定されています。

データがきっちり15列しか無い場合は、以下2つの行がエラーになって`NewData`が出来ないので、その後の2行もエラーになって処理されていないのでは？

```
d15= [x for x in dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,15])]
NewData = np.array([d0, d1,d2, d3,d4, d5,d6, d7,d8, d9,d10, d11,d12, d13,d14, d15])
```

---

**追記:**

例えば以下のCSVファイルを読み取る部分を、

```
data = '1214.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data)
data = np.array(data)
```

こちらのように乱数でシミュレートして17列で10～1000行のデータにしても、処理そのものは完了します。

```
data = []
for _ in range(1000):
    data.append(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 17))

data = np.array(data)
```

ただし、こんな`Warning`が出るのと、出来上がった`NewData`の表示が変なので、望んだ結果とは言えないと思われますが。

表示された`Warning`
`VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray`

結果表示例(データ行数を10にした場合)
[以前のQ&A](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71712/26370)を考えると、縦横が転換されているのと、CSVファイルの各行先頭最後に`[`,`]`が入っているのでCSVデータとは言えない状態です。

```
[list([0.8964406887196086, 0.1289855921390296, 0.9821250613116147, 0.7277624380256356, 0.597179945506056, 0.5883628593677697, 0.46642181807325156, 0.046165752886358935, 0.9831355110804288, 0.8059872223235665])
 list([0.81459734967449, 0.07064141016207148, 0.5683665463277392, 0.5798712084908151, 0.04482624113860545, 0.14102892907620534, 0.39305425436742103, 0.36942030150742966, 0.512619106492389, 0.6764118175476419])
 list([0.7591268875733456, 0.11453918216754855, 0.4647680491351407, 0.040091866778552476, 0.1429846985183626, 0.6627834295485381, 0.09036694991356253, 0.810514260026902, 0.9931642800156654])
 list([0.8625025870468651, 0.3509634752035785, 0.039771391720511695, 0.141294678559875, 0.9785141897412436, 0.7871799464751338, 0.4392150886107685, 0.8797371371672483, 0.8847149683486721])
 list([0.497940921882306, 0.9082257949953394, 0.5833805332031865, 0.47877232055889385, 0.08331201995212023, 0.4006076893255164, 0.47959612630114945, 0.5886402830771224, 0.9980262909358327, 0.5224210756830902])
 list([0.27197735039392024, 0.5755502064358436, 0.6911546654769439, 0.6995193500503479, 0.11448204495653014, 0.28069236013054844, 0.27781231267874995, 0.8300432017199777, 0.5017304070162142, 0.11823577351924519])
 list([0.5923816654094234, 0.42428317216701694, 0.21513107003802912, 0.3246311643857014, 0.8250821738073256, 0.10344631269777493, 0.038894047272288956, 0.467108730492769, 0.9424929679078838])
 list([0.9304845568823439, 0.0949142996713167, 0.197681927245144, 0.6532485659646121, 0.07650063989252631, 0.4641428636069759, 0.4930807358621857, 0.8777035315326964, 0.8079133125265369, 0.27151654275407255])
 list([0.5686227354480835, 0.20979325360116918, 0.41795367528452854, 0.6860058585789381, 0.25969874636294243, 0.3285464977855428, 0.5999579688394171, 0.4151960837685723, 0.9951317222604745, 0.46859183299562845])
 list([0.3783579341561787, 0.6599424089628657, 0.6756485785361779, 0.6579640744721366, 0.48120694336419967, 0.6699040599082838, 0.47013107179808233, 0.7897054241420943, 0.2579579777685834, 0.6984153759229584])
 list([0.2119275007054927, 0.9073692839679351, 0.7542551775514874, 0.7304899190222118, 0.8934351608341778, 0.3759023101892295, 0.06554942790036467, 0.3782961369793859, 0.24940028099595324])
 list([0.4792099212751727, 0.19767858701604624, 0.5162174625431372, 0.019386808204984396, 0.8516704517647707, 0.669500238721486, 0.10275441692328746, 0.7262108016346217, 0.27466330949461903, 0.5114110217107879])
 list([0.4736295383577239, 0.5594249849728473, 0.13118135938803988, 0.6614701297724721, 0.31594547319531097, 0.25538415218610466, 0.38813802091478633, 0.9779182451444076, 0.1292926086118813, 0.7164415691309892])
 list([0.3356971055614466, 0.9960279356408579, 0.9018106146850836, 0.7056349705349919, 0.8677843649824027, 0.713199273910345, 0.4500223204462691, 0.16791339066028255, 0.8083384665780848, 0.06577552973825185])
 list([0.8653470673875016, 0.7158305241304749, 0.9241323423093925, 0.1598556330050731, 0.4655566657028062, 0.3714871548975628, 0.30538053450909164, 0.14440821986341756, 0.9057775689030844, 0.5559513690214988])
 list([0.29634069084155035, 0.7219891196591361, 0.4799806341569959, 0.43549102434868503, 0.675185724281284, 0.5623786004405398, 0.24797232810209235, 0.755702079954496, 0.6220137098402305, 0.31865744944572993])]
```

CSVファイル

```
[0.8964406887196086, 0.1289855921390296, 0.9821250613116147, 0.7277624380256356, 0.597179945506056, 0.5883628593677697, 0.46642181807325156, 0.046165752886358935, 0.9831355110804288, 0.8059872223235665]
[0.81459734967449, 0.07064141016207148, 0.5683665463277392, 0.5798712084908151, 0.04482624113860545, 0.14102892907620534, 0.39305425436742103, 0.36942030150742966, 0.512619106492389, 0.6764118175476419]
[0.7591268875733456, 0.11453918216754855, 0.4647680491351407, 0.040091866778552476, 0.1429846985183626, 0.6627834295485381, 0.09036694991356253, 0.810514260026902, 0.9931642800156654]
[0.8625025870468651, 0.3509634752035785, 0.039771391720511695, 0.141294678559875, 0.9785141897412436, 0.7871799464751338, 0.4392150886107685, 0.8797371371672483, 0.8847149683486721]
[0.497940921882306, 0.9082257949953394, 0.5833805332031865, 0.47877232055889385, 0.08331201995212023, 0.4006076893255164, 0.47959612630114945, 0.5886402830771224, 0.9980262909358327, 0.5224210756830902]
[0.27197735039392024, 0.5755502064358436, 0.6911546654769439, 0.6995193500503479, 0.11448204495653014, 0.28069236013054844, 0.27781231267874995, 0.8300432017199777, 0.5017304070162142, 0.11823577351924519]
[0.5923816654094234, 0.42428317216701694, 0.21513107003802912, 0.3246311643857014, 0.8250821738073256, 0.10344631269777493, 0.038894047272288956, 0.467108730492769, 0.9424929679078838]
[0.9304845568823439, 0.0949142996713167, 0.197681927245144, 0.6532485659646121, 0.07650063989252631, 0.4641428636069759, 0.4930807358621857, 0.8777035315326964, 0.8079133125265369, 0.27151654275407255]
[0.5686227354480835, 0.20979325360116918, 0.41795367528452854, 0.6860058585789381, 0.25969874636294243, 0.3285464977855428, 0.5999579688394171, 0.4151960837685723, 0.9951317222604745, 0.46859183299562845]
[0.3783579341561787, 0.6599424089628657, 0.6756485785361779, 0.6579640744721366, 0.48120694336419967, 0.6699040599082838, 0.47013107179808233, 0.7897054241420943, 0.2579579777685834, 0.6984153759229584]
[0.2119275007054927, 0.9073692839679351, 0.7542551775514874, 0.7304899190222118, 0.8934351608341778, 0.3759023101892295, 0.06554942790036467, 0.3782961369793859, 0.24940028099595324]
[0.4792099212751727, 0.19767858701604624, 0.5162174625431372, 0.019386808204984396, 0.8516704517647707, 0.669500238721486, 0.10275441692328746, 0.7262108016346217, 0.27466330949461903, 0.5114110217107879]
[0.4736295383577239, 0.5594249849728473, 0.13118135938803988, 0.6614701297724721, 0.31594547319531097, 0.25538415218610466, 0.38813802091478633, 0.9779182451444076, 0.1292926086118813, 0.7164415691309892]
[0.3356971055614466, 0.9960279356408579, 0.9018106146850836, 0.7056349705349919, 0.8677843649824027, 0.713199273910345, 0.4500223204462691, 0.16791339066028255, 0.8083384665780848, 0.06577552973825185]
[0.8653470673875016, 0.7158305241304749, 0.9241323423093925, 0.1598556330050731, 0.4655566657028062, 0.3714871548975628, 0.30538053450909164, 0.14440821986341756, 0.9057775689030844, 0.5559513690214988]
[0.29634069084155035, 0.7219891196591361, 0.4799806341569959, 0.43549102434868503, 0.675185724281284, 0.5623786004405398, 0.24797232810209235, 0.755702079954496, 0.6220137098402305, 0.31865744944572993]
```

---

**対処案:**

上記のように色々問題があるようなので、0列目から15列目までを連続で行うのなら、以下のように`for in range()`ループと`pandas`で行うのが良さそうです。

```
work = []
for i in range(16):
    work.append(list(dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, data[:,i])))

df = pd.DataFrame(work).T.fillna('')

print(df)
df.to_csv('1214-945.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: 申し訳ございません。記入ミスでした．csvファイルに16列以上あっても処理が完了しませんでした．

Comment: それはCSVファイルの内容に依存しているのかもしれません。例えば質問に掲載しても問題無いような内容と行数に変換・縮小しても問題が再現するなら、それを質問にテキストで追記してみてください。そうした加工をすると問題が再現しなくなるようでしたら、それが問題発生の条件とかでしょうから、それを調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.dropwhile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)の場合、実行に時間が掛かる場合(状況)があり得るとのことで、

> itertools.dropwhile(predicate, iterable)
>
> Make an iterator that drops elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true; afterwards, returns every element. Note, the iterator does not produce any output until the predicate first becomes false, so **it may have a lengthy start-up time**.

例えば、 `numpy.ndarray` 型の配列で要素数が10^8(1億)、全ての要素が `0.1` であるとすると配列要素の全てが走査される事になります。

```py
z = np.array([0.1]*int(1e8))

print(timeit.timeit(
  'list(dropwhile(lambda y: y < 0.2, z))',
  globals=globals(), number=1))
=>
17.093322979053482 seconds
```

質問者さんの計算機環境(CPUの性能やメモリサイズなど)や実際のデータサイズが判らないので、「1日たっても終わる気配がない」ことの原因が `itertools.dropwhile()` にあるのかどうかは不明です。

ところで、`itertools.dropwhile()` は単純な for loop で実装する事も可能です。また、[Numba: A High Performance Python Compiler](https://numba.pydata.org/) を利用することで高速化する事が可能です。

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np
import timeit

@njit
def dropwhile_njit(lst):
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    if not (lst[i] < 0.2):
      break
  return lst[i:]

z = np.array([0.1]*int(1e8))

print(timeit.timeit(
  'dropwhile_njit(z)',
  globals=globals(), number=1))

=>
0.20109811995644122 seconds
```

Numba 版の方がおおよそ 85 倍高速になります(巨大配列をフルスキャンする場合)。

```
17.093322979053482/0.20109811995644122 = 84.999914
```